# Retrieve search string from request in catalogsearch/block/advanced/form.php

Tags: forms, category-attribute, advanced-search

In catalogsearch/block/advanced/form.php , I guess this function retrieve search string, then user can modify the search he made previously (user can see the previously selected option).

```
public function getAttributeValue($attribute, $part = null)
{
    $value = $this->getRequest()->getQuery($attribute->getAttributeCode());
    if ($part && $value) {
        if (isset($value[$part])) {
            $value = $value[$part];
        } else {
            $value = '';
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

I found many tutorial on how to add Search By Category in Advanced Search Form like [this tutorial](http://vijaymrami.blogspot.fr/2016/06/add-search-by-category-search-option-in.html)

But can not find one that give explicit example on how to retrieve the previously selected category when user modify the search.

Can someone help to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the expected solution, but it's possible to get url parameters

`$category = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('category');`

And then in the option tag, check if url parameter is equal to option value

```
<option <?php if($category == $_category->getId()){echo 'selected';}?> value="<?php echo $_category->getId(); ?>">
     <?php echo $_category->getName();?>
</option>
```